# Avoiding automatic suspension

Tags: suspend

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. If I don't do anything on my terminal for a while, my process is suspended and I need to provide my password to resume.  This seems to be different from the power management settings. Is there a way to avoid this suspension?

I've seen the same behavior in SuSE Leap, and I assume the cure is the same in both cases.

Comment: It sounds like it's a screen locker (screensaver acting just as a screen-locker).  I'm not a KDE user sorry, so I don't know what is the default KDE (Kubuntu) locker, but I'd look in your settings for screensaver; power management yes is different (usually on longer time intervals).

Comment: Can you clarify "my process is suspended and I need to provide my password to resume"? Is your issue that a process you're running in Konsole is suspended but the rest of your Kubuntu applications are unaffected?

Comment: Kubuntu's screen locking I think is managed by SDDM. Default Kubuntu doesn't use screensavers.

Comment: Somehow I feel this has nothing to do with the above. Maybe it's sudo timeout?

Comment: Whatever it is, it was installed by default with no notice, which makes it hard to get rid of.

Comment: Is there a onfiguration file that I can modify to get rid of this obnoxious behavior?  Imposing this effect on the user with no way to modify or nullify it does not seem to me to be good design.

Comment: I tried to report this misbehavior as a bug in the KDE bugtracking system, but my attempt was utterly confounded.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different locations within KDE's system settings that affect this behavior-  **Screen Locking** and **Energy Saving**.

**Configure Screen Locking** allows you to configure if (and after how long) the screen should *lock* after inactivity, and if a password is required to wake.

[image: Screen Locking]

**Energy Saving** allows you to configure if (and after how long) the screen should **turn off**, as well as other options to save power.

[image: Energy Saving]