# Font for Firefox main menu and similar

Tags: fonts

I' running Kubuntu 18.04.  How can I set a larger font for the Firefox main menu (and similar menus)?  The font setting in System Settings doesn't affect it.

Comment: The GTK font setting isn't sufficient.  I solved this problem years ago but I couldn't remember what I did.  I believe that the trick is to log in as root and then set the font.  That's the only way that Firefox (and some other apps) will pay attention to it.  (I'm writing this post without yet having fully checked out the situation.)

Comment: hmmm.. I am running KDE plasma v 5.15.5 and changing that setting changes the fonts in firefox menus and other GTK apps

Comment: see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/CjfaWH7 -- outrageous "wargames" font used for emphasis

Comment: "I believe that the trick is to log in as root and then set the font. That's the only way that Firefox (and some other apps) will pay attention to it." is quite unnecessary unless you plan to run Firefox as root which can be dangerous.

Comment: @Nmath it's difficult to understand what the poster means by "and similar" in the title and by "and some other apps" in a comment. So offering specific guidance isn't easy. A similar situation exists in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146690/avoiding-automatic-suspension where clarifications asked for are still to be provided :(

Answer (score 0):

To change the font or font size in GTK applications in KDE you can use the **Gnome/GTK Application Style** settings.

You can access these settings in **System Settings > Application Style > GNOME / GTK Application Style**.  You can also find it in the Application Launcher.

You will notice that you have options to set a completely different theme for GTK2 and GTK3 applications.  You will also have the option to change the font (and font size) in GTK applications.  This will affect the menus in GTK applications like Mozilla Firefox.

**Before Settings Change:** 
[image: before settings change]

**After Settings Change:** 
[image]

To address your concern about running applications as root: you do not need to run anything as root to make this change.  The settings can be changed and adjusted through the regular system settings.

Comment: I inadvertently cause some confusion by asking a related question: how to increase the (application) font size for non-KDE applications.  The answer to this question is clear: use the Gnome application style (GDK) setting in System Settings to change the font size for the Firefox menu.  The other question -- increasing the (application) font size in non-KDE applications -- remains unanswered.